# How to access nested NSDictionary item

Tags: nsdictionary

```
Sections =     (
            {
        EnglishName = whatsnew;
        ID = 1;
        Name = "What's New";
        ParentSectionID = 0;
    }
```

this is the dictionary i want to acces Name of can i access it.

Comment: Can you give further information? and what codes did you try ?

Comment: i want to access object for key@"Name" from nsmutable dictionary

Answer (score 0):

From OP comment, here is the way to obtain **name** value in the `NSMutableDictionary` :

( assume your NSMutableDictionary is named as `Sections` ):

```
NSString *name = (NSString *)[Sections objectForKey:@"Name"];
```